# Type hints when only a subset of attribute types are accepted

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Say I have a class with multiple possible types for an attribute and a function that only works on some of these types.

How would I type-hint that function so that it specifies it only accepts some of the types accepted by the original class?

```py
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Foo:
    a: int | str

def plus_1_a(foo: Foo) -> None:
    """This will only work if foo.a is an int, not a string."""
    foo.a += 1
```

Comment: As written you'd have to use a _protocol_ for "things that have an `a` attribute that's an `int`", because `Foo` isn't generic in terms of that type.

Comment: it's not really clear to me what you are trying to do. You cannot type hint it with `Foo`, because you've already declared that `a` is an `int | str`. So, I guess you can use a Protocol, but note, you won't be able to pass  a`Foo` to it, because `Foo` won't adhere to that protocol.

Comment: Perhaps, can you give an example of how you expect this to actually work? Because note, if you do something like `foo = Foo(a=1)`, type checkers are still going to consider `f.a` to have the type `int | str`, at least, I don't think either `mypy` or `pyright` will narrow in this case

Comment: but just in general, union types should be avoided, because once you commit to using a union type, you commit to using `if isinstance(x, whatever): ... else raise SomeError` everywhere in your code that you actually want to use that type in any non-trivial way and still be type safe (i.e. pass static analysis)

Comment: eh yeah I was hoping to avoid a protocol here—but looks like that's the only option @jonrsharpe.

thanks here!

Comment: Why don't you just make it generic? `Foo[Generic[A]]`, where `A = TypeVar("A", bound=int | str)`, then declare `plus_1_a(foo: Foo[int])`

Comment: @dROOOze you would want `A = TypeVar("A", int, str)`, if your bound is a union, you are right back to the same problem!

Comment: @PauloCosta but I'm not sure a protocol would actually help you here

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the union bound is fine - you can try it on [mypy-play.net](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=6920c7ec20685718b6f2fc630024414a). `T`'s upper bound being `int | str` doesn't mean that `Foo[int]` becomes `Foo[int | str]`.

Comment: oh yeah [you're right](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=04c81173ee10fb595498862dbe25f628&flags=strict). (also TIL you can create a link to code on mypy-play)

Answer (score 0):

Consider making `Foo` generic over the type of `a`.

```py
import dataclasses
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", int, str)


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Foo(Generic[T]):
    a: T


def plus_1_a(foo: Foo[int]) -> None:
    """This will only work if foo.a is an int, not a string."""
    foo.a += 1
```